# Timer for every 1s repeat

Tags: java, timer

I created a Manager of Timer (java.util) for my system. I want to be executed every 1s. I've tried this :

```
public class GlobalManager extends Timer {

public static GlobalManager manager;
public static ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Manageable> datas = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

public GlobalManager() {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("GlobalManager");
    this.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskExecutor(), 0, 1000);

}

/* Manage the data in the waiting queue.. */
public static class TaskExecutor extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(datas.size());
        for(Manageable data : datas) {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - data.startTime) >= data.delay) {
                data.run();

                if(data.removeAfterRun)
                    datas.remove(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem occurs while running. It prints out a line with the size of the data every 1s.
When the data.run() is executed, it does not continue to println every 1s, instead it waits a quite long time for the next print.

Why?

Comment: How long does it take to loop through everything in `datas` and run the ones that need it? I don't believe that scheduled tasks will run until the current one completes, so if it takes longer than 1 second to process your data, your next task won't execute on time.

Comment: how long and hard is your run method? put it in a thread though if they can't run at the same time your out of luck either way

Comment: Are you directly executing the run() method? (you shouldn't)

Comment: @MikeR The `run()` method is automatically executed at a scheduled rate via `this.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);`

Comment: @azurefrog yes I know, just making sure OP is not trying to execute it himself directly somewhere else in the code...

Comment: What is `data.run();`? Also, you can't remove() an entry from a Collection while you iterate it with a for-each loop. You're supposed to call `remove()` on the `Iterator` directly.

Answer (score 0):

How much costs `data.run`? 
A timer is not designed to process a big amount of synchronous work with undefined run time.
You can start a 'worker' thread inside the timers run method instead.

The following example shows how the internal run time effects the time between the periodical calls.

```
package test.threads;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest extends Timer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new TimerTest().startTimer();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        this.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskExecutor(), 0, 1000);
    }

    public static class TaskExecutor extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);//<-- Increases the rate to at least 2 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but I've see, I can't use this solution, because I need yo check all my data every 1s to count how many time it start, so I have look for Executor and use two global variable, one With an Executer.schedulerThreadPool(5); and newSingleThreadExecutor
And they run with ont problem over 11hours or +

Its the best solution i've found.
Problem solved